# SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad, synaptics

My touch pad only works before I sign into my Ubuntu account. After signing in I lose control of my touch pad and the mouse pointer stops moving as I try to move it. It all happened suddenly, it was working yesterday but now it doesn't.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: It is 18.04 LST

Comment: Is it a clean install, or did you upgrade from another version?

Comment: clean. It's been working perfectly for a long time.

Comment: Does the issue resolve itself within a minute, or is the pointer frozen for more than a few minutes?

Comment: I suggest you create a new user account and test whether the problem persists in the new account. This way, you see whether the problem is in the user configuration, or system wide.

Comment: Not transient .

Comment: I monitored the log file and it says device removed.

Comment: What's the output of `uptime` and `free -h`? Use `Ctl`  + `Alt`+ `F2`, then login, then run the command if the GUI freezes

Comment: I added a new user and tested, it works.